# Want to control volume like windows in crunchbang++ OS

Tags: debian, openbox, volume, crunchbang

How can I configure the volume up and down keys on my keyboard? I press the volume up, down, and mute keys, but it doesn't work. I want to control volume like windows OS.

##### About my OS

**OS**: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) x86_64

**Kernel**: 5.10.0-21-amd64

**Packages**: 1869 (dpkg)

**DE**: x-session-manager

**WM**: Openbox

Answer (score 0):

You should have a file `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml` where you may place individual keybindings such as:

```
<keybind key="S-F2">
  <action name="Execute">
    <command>/usr/bin/amixer set Master "3%+"</command>
  </action>
</keybind>
```

Where `S` is you <kbd>fn</kbd> key.

Log out and in to ensure the new rc-file is loaded.

Comment: I found this file. Also, put what you provided. It's not working. I want to configure this - 
`key:  "AudioVolumeUp"
keyCode:  175`
and others also.